# Linq join efficiency question

Tags: c#, linq, performance

```
// Loop each users profile
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var q = (from P in db.tblProfiles orderby P.UserID descending select new { LastUpdated = P.ProfileLastUpdated, UserID = P.UserID }).ToList();
    foreach(var Rec in q){
        string Username = db.tblForumAuthors.SingleOrDefault(author => author.Author_ID == Rec.UserID).Username;
        AddURL(("Users/" + Rec.UserID + "/" + Username), Rec.LastUpdated.Value, ChangeFrequency.daily, 0.4);
    }
}
```

This is for my sitemap, printing a URL for each users profile on the system.  But say we have 20,000 users, is the Username query going to slow this down significantly?

I'm used to having the join in the SQL query, but having it separated from the main query and in the loop seems like it could be inefficient unless it compiles it well.

Comment: Well calling `ToList()` on it will slow it down unnecessarily.  There's no need to have it there since you're just enumerating through the collection.  It will benefit by using an actual join since it won't be run locally, but on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will probably be unbearably slow. In your case this will issue 20,000 separate SQL queries to the database. Since the queries run synchronously, you will incur the server communication overhead on each iteration. The delay will accumulate quite fast.

Go with a join.

```
from P in db.tblProfiles
join A in db.tblForumAuthors on P.UserID equals A.Author_ID
orderby P.UserID descending
select new { LastUpdated = P.ProfileLastUpdated, UserID = P.UserID, Username = A.Username };
```

By the way, `SingleOrDefault(...).Username` will throw a NullReferenceException if the `author` is missing. Better use `Single()` or check your logic.

Comment: Added the needed LINQ join. You can use this manual join, or go with George Polevoy's solution. I like his better, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have constranints set up correctly in your database while designing the DataContext,  then the designer should generate a one-to-one members in your Profile and Author classes.
If not, you can do it manually in designer.
Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
var q =
 from profile in db.tblProfiles
 order by profile.UserID descending
 select new {
  LastUpdated = profile.ProfileLastUpdated,
  profile.UserID,
  profile.Author.Username
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the JOIN!

Save yourself from unnecessary database access, join and get everything you need in a single shot!